# Will it cost more memory if I do not truncate my data and just set limit when plotting contours?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

Is it necessary for me to truncate my data when plotting contours with limits set?

Will it cost more memory if I do not truncate the data?

Comment: What do you mean with truncating and limits? The size of your arrays (e.g. only setting `xlim(x[n1],x[n2])` without slicing the input like `x[n1:n2]`), or the data (e.g. limiting your data like `data[data>10]=10` when setting the upper level of the contours to `10`)? In the first case I would say yes, the second case I would guess no, but you could test it.

Comment: @Bart Thank you, I mean the first case. And the second case also inspires me . Thanks again!